# Next 13 Image Sizing in Flexbox

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am building a website with Next.js 13 and Tailwind. I am currently stuck with a simple flexbox size problem. However, can't find a solution. My goal is that the two FlexboxItems have the same width for medium and larger screens and the same height for smaller screen dimensions.
The one with the width on larger screens also works. Only on smaller screens are the items not of the same height.

```
<div className=" bg-slate-500 min-h-screen flex md:flex-row flex-col">
           <div className="bg-orange-400 flex-1 flex flex-col justify-center content-center flex-wrap text-4xl">
              <h1>Text</h1>
           </div>
           <div className="bg-lime-500 flex-1 flex flex-col justify-center">
              <Image
                 src={FreeSquareImg}
                 alt="Sample"
                 className="rounded-3xl"/>
           </div>
  </div>
```

[image: larger screens:]

[image: smaller screens:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give equal height `h-1/2` to both the div and control the width of the image so that it does not comes of the green div.

Below is the code that help you

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex h-screen flex-col bg-slate-500 sm:flex-row">
  <div class="flex h-1/2 flex-1 flex-col flex-wrap content-center justify-center bg-orange-400 text-4xl">
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="flex h-1/2 flex-1 flex-col justify-center bg-lime-500">
    <image src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_blue.s2014.png" alt="Sample" class="mx-auto w-1/2 rounded-3xl sm:w-full sm:p-12" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also view the mobile and other screen view [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0UztMs47CN?size=356x588)